# The home page and questions page should have the same content

Tags: feature-request, homepage

The **home page** has the following tabs:

[image]

and the **questions page** has the following tabs:

[image]

They both have a featured tab, but the home page has four tabs that the questions page doesn't, and the questions page was five tabs that the home page doesn't.

This is confusing and frustrating:

- If I'm on the home page and want to see the unanswered questions, I have to press Questions and the unanswered.
- If I'm on the questions page and want to see the hot questions, I have to press the site logo and then the hot tab.

The home page should be the same as the questions page. There's not an obvious distinction between them: they both display lists of several types of questions.

Answer (score 4):

As those pages have different purposes, they cannot have the same content.

- The purpose of the front page is showing part of the questions; it shows those questions that, for one reason or another, are important to see: questions that have been recently edited, recently asked, or for which an answer was recently given, or edited (the "interesting" tab); questions with an open bounty (the "featured" tab); "hot" questions.
- The purpose of the "questions" page is listing all the questions by sorting them basing on different criteria. The only tab that doesn't sort questions is the "featured" tab, which (in both the pages) shows the questions with an open bounty. The difference is that the list of the featured questions shown in the front page is (possibly) partial.

Some of the tabs make sense in a page, but not in the other one. For example, the "hot" tab makes sense in the front page, as it lists some of the questions basing in their *hotness*; in the "questions" page, the "hot" tab would not make sense, as the "questions" page lists all the questions, and the *hotness* would be a criteria to sort the questions, not a criteria to pick-up some questions to show.

Those pages *need* to have different content.
Without the front page, it would not be possible to notice spammed posts; new answers to old questions would get less votes, as the users who would notice them would be the users who asked the question and who receive a notification about new answers given for their questions. Vice versa, there are times where the need is just to look at the latest asked questions, not to those old questions that received a recent answer or have been recently edited.

If you are speaking of merging the pages, I disagree with that for two reasons:

- The number of tabs in a page would be excessive. Instead of having a maximum of 6 tabs, there would be 10 tabs.
- The purpose of the front page is showing part of the questions which are more relevant basing on different criteria; it is not showing all the questions in a site.

Comment: This answer doesn't really make sense. If the pages were merged, *there would be no less access to information than there is now*. Everything you can see now could still be seen, except that you don't have to keep track of whichever page it was arbitrarily put on. Also, the distinction your making between the front page and the questions page isn't actually true: both pages have filtered lists of questions, and sorted lists of questions.

Comment: You didn't speak of merging them: You said they should have the same content, which could as mean "pick the content of one of the pages, and show it in both the cases."

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make that clear; anyway, the intention is to put all of the content in one place, instead of having them arbitrarily separated.

Comment: I still answered to your question when I said that the front page has a different purpose than the "questions" page. Both the pages list questions, but the front page lists those questions that are considered worth to be shown to who visits the front page. I think it is what normally happens with the front page of most of the sites.

Comment: I disagree; as it stands, the home page serves NO purpose.  The only apparent difference is the navigation options at the top.  You can click on "active" on the questions page and get the same list of questions the home page shows. It's just confusing to users.

Comment: @Spencer Actually, the home page sorts the questions basing on different criteria. If you want to see questions where an answer was recently added or edited, you don't click on the _Questions_ tab.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't think that's a big enough difference  .

Comment: @Spencer Still, it's a difference.